# Python 2 to 3 port - Still has one more error

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am porting a program called markovgenerator I found on the web from Python2 to Python3.  It all seems to work just fine.

Here is the code: (Python3 version)

```
import random

class Markov:
    def __init__(self, file, size):
        self.size = size
        self.starts = []
        self.cache = {}
        self.file_to_words(file)
        self.parse_words()

    def file_to_words(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        data = file.read()
        self.words = data.split("\n")

    def tuples(self, word):
        if len(word) < self.size - 1:
            return
        word = word + "\n"
        for i in range(len(word) - self.size):
            yield (word[i:i+self.size], word[i+self.size])


    def parse_words(self):
        for word in self.words:
            self.starts.append(word[:self.size])
            for key, next in self.tuples(word):
                if key in self.cache:
                    self.cache[key].append(next)
                else:
                    self.cache[key] = [next]

    def generate_word(self):
        key = random.choice(self.starts)
        word = key
        next = random.choice(self.cache[key])
        while next != "\n":
            word = word + next
            key = key[1:] + next
            next = random.choice(self.cache[key])
        return word

from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-p', type='int', dest='prev_num', default=3,
                  help='number of previous letters to base chain on')
    parser.add_option('-n', type='int', dest='num', default=5,
                  help='number of generated words')
    parser.add_option('-s', '--source-text', type='string',
                  default='wordlist-en.txt', dest='source',
                  help='file to use as basis for generating the words')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    file = open('alice.txt')
    markov = Markov(file, options.prev_num)
    file.close()
    for i in range(options.num):
        print(markov.generate_word())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Except I get this error:

```
next = random.choice(self.cache[key])
KeyError: ''
```

The error appears in the "generate_word()" function.
It must be from the translation to 3.  Any ideas?  I dont see why I am getting a key error, as I pass key to other places no problem.

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like you potentially append to `self.starts` without adding a key to the cache when `parse_words` calls `tuples` (`tuples` checks `len(word)`, `parse_words` does not).

Comment: Does alice.txt actually have data in it? If it is empty then you never build a cache.

Comment: It does, I actually tweaked it from what little I know so far of Py_v3.  I got it to work, so far my favorite line generated from 2001: A space Odyssey Ch.30 is:  "At his first glimpse of TMA-1, with the help of drugs, hypnosis, and visual effects - under the bridge - in the next few hours he waits."

Comment: That has got to be the best quote I have ever heard.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes that error, and ignores any blank lines outputted:

```
import random

class Markov:
    def __init__(self, file, size):
        self.size = size
        self.starts = []
        self.cache = {}
        self.file_to_words(file)
        self.parse_words()
        self.cache[''] = '\n'

    def file_to_words(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        data = file.read()
        self.words = data.split("\n")

    def tuples(self, word):
        if len(word) < self.size - 1:
            return
        word = word + "\n"
        for i in range(len(word) - self.size):
            yield (word[i:i+self.size], word[i+self.size])


    def parse_words(self):
        for word in self.words:
            self.starts.append(word[:self.size])
            for key, next in self.tuples(word):
                if key in self.cache:
                    self.cache[key].append(next)
                else:
                    self.cache[key] = [next]

    def generate_word(self):
        key = random.choice(self.starts)
        word = key
        next = random.choice(self.cache[key])
        while not next == "\n":
            word = word + next
            key = key[1:] + next
            next = random.choice(self.cache[key])
        return word

from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-p', type='int', dest='prev_num', default=3,
                  help='number of previous letters to base chain on')
    parser.add_option('-n', type='int', dest='num', default=5,
                  help='number of generated words')
    parser.add_option('-s', '--source-text', type='string',
                  default='wordlist-en.txt', dest='source',
                  help='file to use as basis for generating the words')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    file = open('alice.txt')
    markov = Markov(file, options.prev_num)
    file.close()
    iters = 0
    while iters < options.num:
        word = markov.generate_word()
        if word != '\n' and word != '':
          print(word)
          iters += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For some reason, the string `''`, which raises `KeyError` when you try to use it in the dictionary `cache`, was registering as a word. Everything I tried to remove it caused the program to break, so I added a line to `__init__` which sets the next word of `''` to `\n`, giving the intended result by quitting when we see a newline.
If there's anything wrong with this code, let me know and I will be happy to fix it.

Comment: @11thZone: If this question sufficiently solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI: Can you give some more detail about what you changed to make it work and why?

Comment: @AlexA. Should be fixed now. Thanks!